# setLaunchPath: @"/bin/ps" is crashing when running in iPhone device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, process

I wanted to set the setLaunchPath: @"/bin/ps" for my iPhone application what actually it will do? Application crashes and will give the error as -  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'launch path not accessible'
*** First throw call stack:

Answer (score 2):

["`setLaunchPath`" exists in NSTask under MacOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTask/setLaunchPath%3a)... perhaps it exists under iOS, but it is **not documented** and certainly wouldn't be allowed for sandboxed apps that get submitted to the Apple App Store.

Comment: NSTask isn't even public on iOS. If OP wants to get a list of processes, he'll need to use something else.

Comment: I know that it is private api.But i want to jail break the application and use it,Can we do that?How can we do it.